# Dapper - Insert using nested object

Tags: c#, insert, dapper

I have a class `User` with a nested class `Bank`.

```
class User{
        int Id;
        string username;
        Bank bank;

    }

    Class Bank{
        int id;
        string name;
    }
```

I need to create an Insert function for `User`. Is there a way in `Dapper`to execute a query and binding the parameters from a nested a object ?

Comment: You could just create an anonymous class `new { UserId = u.Id, UserName = u.username, BankId = u.bank.id, BankName = u.bank.name }`

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing right now, I was wondering is there's a way to do it just by passing an instance of the User class

Comment: Maybe you can create a mapper to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom mapper for **Dapper** using **DapperExtensions**:

```
public sealed class UserMapper : ClassMapper<User>
{
    public UserMapper()
    {
        Map(x => x.bank.id).Column("BankId");
        Map(x => x.bank.name).Column("BankName");

        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Customized-mapping-for-a-class

Make sure you register the assembly containing the mapper:

```
DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new[] { typeof(UserMapper).Assembly });
```

Comment: And then what? This answer is either incorrect or incomplete. When I try to use @BankId in my query it is not using the BankId that is mapped in the ClassMapper. It just throws an SQL exception `Must declare the scalar variable "@BankId"`. How do you actually use that nested class in the query after you map it?

Answer (score 1):

For such a scenario where not just a `User` object but a `List<User>` might also need a db insertion, you can consider using `table valued parameters`.  For your question it would be:

- Use `IEnumerable<User>` and `IEnumerable<Bank>`, even if it is just one object
- Make the `TVP` with appropriate schema and same order of `columns` as in `IEnumerable collection` for the stored procedure, else it will lead to error
- You can use `dynamic parameters` to bind the parameters, where for `TVP`, `IEnumerable` can be supplied using extension method `AsTableValuedParameters` in case you are using `anonymous type` parameters not `dynamic parameters`, then use the `ObjectReader` from `FastMember` in Nuget to convert `IEnuemrable<T>` to `Datatable`, which is mandatory for TVP. Even custom code can be used for `IEnuemrable<T>` to `Datatable` conversion, in case few columns need to be omitted, following is the code snippet:

---

```
public static DataTable CreateTable<TDataTable>(this IEnumerable<TDataTable> collection)
{
    // Fetch the type of List contained in the ParamValue
    var tableType = typeof(TDataTable);

    // Create DataTable which will contain data from List<T>
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    // Fetch the Type fields count
    var columnCount = tableType.GetProperties().Count();

    var columnNameMappingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // Create DataTable Columns using table type field name and their types
    // Traversing through Column Collection
    for (var counter = 0; counter < columnCount; counter++)
    {
        var propertyInfo = tableType.GetProperties()[counter]; 

        var columnName = propertyInfo.Name;

        columnNameMappingDictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name,
            propertyInfo.Name);

        // Fetch the current type of a property and check whether its nullable type before adding a column
        var currentType = tableType.GetProperties()[counter].PropertyType;

        dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(currentType) ?? currentType);
    }

    // Return parameter with null value
    if (collection == null)
        return dataTable;

    // Traverse through number of entries / rows in the List
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        // Create a new DataRow
        var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

        foreach (var columnName in columnNameMappingDictionary.Select(propertyinfo => propertyinfo.Value))
        {
            dataRow[columnName] = item.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }
        // Add Row to Table
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return (dataTable);
}
```